# How to iterate new class intances over a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I have an array which looks like this:

```
var array = ["name", " zip", " city", " 51.408", "1.333", " 5.008", "name2", "zip2", "city2", " 51.404", "4.999", "2.434"]
```

It contains data from 2 users. I want to create 2 instances of a class below.

```
class User {
    constructor(name, zip, city, x, y) {
        this.name = name;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.city = city;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
```

The 6th and the last element of the array is not used in the class.

This is an iteration I wrote:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    var user1 = new User(arrayData[i], arrayData[i+1], arrayData[i+2], arrayData[i+3], arrayData[i+4], arrayData[i+5])
    var user2 = new User(arrayData[i+6], arrayData[i+7], arrayData[i+8], arrayData[i+9], arrayData[i+10], arrayData[i+11])

}
```

It works fine but as you can see this is not a really smart peace of code. I want to make it better. Also, I don't know how to make it works for n number of users. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
var users = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 6) {
//                                ^^^^^^
    var user = new User(arrayData[i], arrayData[i+1], arrayData[i+2], arrayData[i+3], arrayData[i+4], arrayData[i+5]);
    users.push(user);
}
console.log(users);
```

<sub>(Using `i+5 < array.length` for the loop condition would be more accurate, but doesn't matter as long as it's guaranteed the array length is always a multiple of 6)</sub>

@trincot follows the same idea and achieves the same result with more concise code (mapping, slicing, spreading), I tried to keep it as simple as the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop should really only create one user in its body, and `i` should increment with steps of 6.

You can also use a parameter spread to avoid you have to address the five argument separately.

Finally, with `Array.from` you can loop and create an array of users:

```js
class User {
    constructor(name, zip, city, x, y) {
        this.name = name;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.city = city;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

var array = ["name", " zip", " city", " 51.408", "1.333", " 5.008", "name2", "zip2", "city2", " 51.404", "4.999", "2.434"];

let users = Array.from({length: array.length / 6}, (_, i) => 
    new User(...array.slice(i*6, i*6+5)) // Not including the unused 6th value
);

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Is `i*6+5` an off-by-one error or accounting for "*The 6th […] element […] is not used*"? If the latter, it should have a comment

Comment: Yes, I confirm it is the latter & comment added.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `reduce` method with `%` remainder operator to get every `nth` element and then use `slice` with rest operator to get data for the class instance.

```js
var array = ["name", " zip", " city", " 51.408", "1.333", " 5.008", "name2", "zip2", "city2", " 51.404", "4.999", "2.434"]

class User {
  constructor(name, zip, city, x, y) {
    this.name = name;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.city = city;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

const users = array.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
  if (i % 6 === 0) {
    const props = a.slice(i, i + 6);
    const user = new User(...props);
    r.push(user);
  }

  return r;
}, [])

console.log(users)
```